# I'm trying to upload a file using a POST request. file is not getting uploaded

Tags: python, api, file-upload, robotframework, web-api-testing

This API URL is working in swagger and postman

*** Settings ***
    Library  RequestsLibrary
    Library  Collections

```
*** Variables ***
${base_URL}=    https://someurl.com

${file_name}=   Get Binary File   Test.png

*** Test Cases ***
TC008_Upload_File

    create session      upload_file     ${base_url}
    ${body}=    create dictionary      asset=${file_name}
    ${header}=  create dictionary      Content-Type=multipart/form-data:boundary= <calculated when request is sent> Accept=text/plain

    ${response}=    post request   upload_file  /api/insertFile  data=${body}  headers=${header}
    log to console      ${response.content}
      #to validate status code with the actual status code
     ${Status_code}=    convert to string   ${response.status_code}
     should be equal    ${Status_code}      200

     #to validate the content of the response body
     ${response_body}=  convert to string   ${response.content}
     should contain     ${response_body}    true
```

My Curl URL is:

```
curl -X POST "https://someurl.com/api/insertFile" -H "accept: text/plain" -H "Content-Type: multipart/form-data" -F "asset=@Test.png;type=image/png"
```

Comment: So, what does "file is not uploaded" mean? What's the response body? What does the server log say? Is it you really putting in the "boundary" header, or the library (and note the `:` in front of it)?

Comment: It is giving me 200 always in server log also expected response is true but getting false every time. Although the same API is working perfectly in the Postman tool. Yes boundary header is required while sending this post request. Not sure if I have writing the code perfectly or do l missing anything that is needed to work this API

Comment: POST Request : url=https://someurl/api/insertFile 
 path_url=/api/insertFile 
 headers={'User-Agent': 'python-requests/2.23.0', 'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate', 'Accept': 'text/plain', 'Connection': 'keep-alive', 'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data:boundary=<>', 'Content-Length': '106'} body=asset=Get+Binary+File+C%3A%5CUsers%5Cfl792%5CPycharmProjects%5CResrAssured%5CVideoGameProject%5CTest15.txt   
14:51:34.134 INFO POST Response : url=https://someurl/api/insertFile 
 status=200, reason=OK  body=false INFO${response} = <Response [200]>

Comment: POST Response : url=https://someurl/api/insertFile 
 status=200, reason=OK 
 body=false

Comment: OK, just spotted one solid reason for your issue - but can't guarantee it's the only one. Answer coming.

Answer (score 0):

You obviously want to have a file's content as the request's body, but - you are trying to get it in the variables section:

```
*** Variables ***
${base_URL}=    https://someurl.com

${file_name}=   Get Binary File   Test.png     # <-- this call here
```

In that place - the Variables section - you can't run keywords and assign their returned value to a variable; everything put there becomes the value directly (even if it resembles a keyword name). Thus `${file_name}`'s value is actually "Get Binary File C:\Users\fl792\PycharmProjects\ResrAssured\VideoGameProject\Test15.txt", not that file's content.

You can fix that by moving it inside a callable place - like the test case itself:

```
*** Test Cases ***
TC008_Upload_File
    ${file_name}=   Get Binary File   Test.png
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing the knowledge. updated scripts as per your suggestions Create Session    alias    ${uri}
    ${file_name}=   Get Binary File   Test.png
    ${headers}=      Create Dictionary     Accept=plain/text     Content-Type=multipart/form-data:boundary=<>
    ${data}=   create dictionary  asset=${file_name}
    ${resp}=  post request  alias  /api/insertFile  data=${file_name}  headers=${headers}
    Should Be Equal As Strings    ${resp.status_code}    200
    log to console  ${resp.content}
    log to console  ${resp.headers}

Comment: But still receiving false in response. But in log Seeing below data now POST Request : url=https://fulcrumone-fileuploadblob.westus.cloudapp.azure.com/api/insertFile 
 path_url=/api/insertFile 
 headers={'User-Agent': 'python-requests/2.23.0', 'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate', 'Accept': 'plain/text', 'Connection': 'keep-alive', 'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data:boundary=<>', 'Content-Length': '199882'}  body=b'\x89PNG\r\n\x1a\n\x00\x00\x00\rIHDR\x00\x00\x05V\x00\x00\x03\x00\x08\x06\x00\x00\x00\

Comment: Well, it gets API specific from here, you should see with the server's log and logic what is not correct. There is one thing that does look out of place - you do continue to put the `boundary` header manually, it doesn't have an (actual) value, and it's with a semicolon before it - all of these should be fixed.

Comment: Data will be put in boundary when we sent post request. Though the same API is working in Swagger and Postman.

Comment: Your log says otherwise; you are setting a literal string. Looks like you've copied the header from Postman - where that string, "<calculated when request is sent>", is actually a hint to the user that this is something the program is going to calculate, just before it actually makes the request. That's an http header, that follows specific rules for setting and usage.